# Is Spring Cloud Config servers compatible with GitOps?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud-config

The original idea of Spring Cloud Config Server was to allow you to centralize configurations. This way, you could change the code independently of the configuration.

However, the code won and everything is now code, including your infrastructure. Typical paradigms that promote this are GitOps and ArgoCD.

And so my question: does it  make sense in 2021 to have a Spring Cloud Config server when deploying Spring Microservices to a K8S environment?

Answer (score 1):

It definitely might be redundant but it depends a lot on your exact workflows. If you are only using the git backend then I would try going without but practice all your common flows (deploy new version of code, of config, rollbacks of each, emergency hotfixes, disaster recovery). Platform-native tools will generally have better integration on the platform side, while framework-native tools will have better on framework side :) You can also split the difference with the SCCS filesystem backend.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Cloud Config is just a tool, like many others.
So its up to you to decide whether to use it or not.

In a nutshell, with the Cloud Config Server you can keep all the configuration in git, and once configured correctly, it will automatically pull the configuration changes from the git repository.

It exposes the REST API so you can query it from any kind of application, but it especially shines when you have spring boot powered microservices, because you can ask for the "relevant pieces" of the configuration really easily, and it will naturally map to Spring Boot's way of accessing the configuration inside the microservice. In addition you can automatically refresh the beans upon the configuration change without restarting the application. This is something that you can't easily achieve with a non-spring-aware solution.

Whether you should use it? Well, it depends on your workflows, requirements, the current state of the system, and many non-technical factors.

I've found the answer that I by myself posted about the comparison of k8s ConfigMaps and Cloud Config Server: [Here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59139965/spring-cloud-config-server-vs-configmaps-for-cloud-kubernetes) I think, it might be relevant.